# Ubuntu 15.04 install ubiquity crash

Tags: 14.04, 15.04

I go to install the New Ubuntu from my USB drive, Try Ubuntu works and i can get on the internet. It asks me to select my language - check, asks me to select country-check, then asks me to select a partition and freezes - pop up says "Ubiquity has crashed" the computer then shuts down

Comment: I have the same problem when i'm creating a encrypted partion. Any solution?   Dell m2800 ubuntu 15.04 UEFI installation.